Wilks' theorem, confidence regions on a projected subspace?
Background
My context is I am thinking about maximum likelihood estimation of a parameter $\theta\in \mathbb{R}^r$ by drawing samples $\{x_i\}$ from a distribution which depends on $\theta$. I know how to write the log-likelihood function
$$
\ell(\theta) = \log(\mathcal{L}(\theta))
$$
where $\mathcal{L}(\theta)$ is the likelihood of observing the dataset $\{x_i\}$ assuming the value of $\theta$ for the parameter. I know how to calculate the maximum likelihood estimator
$$
\hat{\theta} = \text{argmax}_{\theta}(\ell(\theta))
$$
I also know that if $\theta_0$ is the true parameter value then the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is asymptotically distributed as
$$
\hat{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta_0, \mathcal{I}^{-1})
$$
where the Fisher information matrix $\mathcal{I}$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{I}_{ij} = -\frac{\partial^2 \ell(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j} \Bigg \vert_{\hat{\theta}}
$$

Manipulations for $r$-dimensional confidence region
Furthermore, I know how to make the following manipulations
$$
\begin{align*}
\ell(\theta_0) \approx& \ell(\hat{\theta}) - \frac{1}{2} (\theta_0 - \hat{\theta})^T \mathcal{I} (\theta_0 - \hat{\theta})\\ 
\Lambda(\theta_0) = 2(\ell(\hat{\theta}) - \ell(\theta_0)) =& (\hat{\theta} - \theta_0)^T \mathcal{I} (\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) = \Delta\theta^T \mathcal{I} \Delta\theta\\
=& \Delta \theta^T L^T L \Delta \theta
\end{align*}
$$
Where $\mathcal{I} = L^TL$ is the Cholesky decomposition of $\mathcal{I}$. Let
$$
Z = L \Delta \theta = L(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0)
$$
but we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{\theta} \sim& \mathcal{N}(\theta_0, \mathcal{I}^{-1}) = \mathcal{N}(\theta_0, (L^TL)^{-1}) = \mathcal{N}(\theta_0, L^{-1}(L^T)^{-1})\\
\hat{\theta} - \theta_0 \sim& \mathcal{N}(0, L^{-1}(L^T)^{-1})\\
L(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) \sim& \mathcal{N}(0, LL^{-1}(L^T)^{-1}L^T) = \mathcal{N}(0, I)
\end{align*}
$$
So we see that $Z$ is distributed as a multivariate standard normal distribution.
This means $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ so that
$$
\Lambda(\theta_0) = Z^T Z = \sum_{i=1}^r Z_i^2 \sim \chi^2_r
$$
If we want a confidence region with level $p$ we can construct it by
$$
C(p) = \{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^r:\Lambda(\theta) < \text{PPF}_{\chi^2_r}(p)\}
$$
Then
$$
P(\theta_0 \in C(p)) = P(\Lambda(\theta_0) < \text{PPF}_{\chi^2_r}(p)) = \text{CDF}_{\chi^2_r}(\text{PPF}_{\chi^2_r}(p)) = p
$$
as desired.

The question: what about projecting onto a lower-dimensional subspace?
I find the above story very nice and satisfactory, and even simple in some senses. However, I get very confused when trying to understand how to find confidence regions for a subset of parameters of $\theta_0$. For example if I just want a confidence interval for $(\theta_0)_i$ or more generally if I want a joint confidence interval for $\theta_0$ projected onto some $s$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^r$.
In fact, I'm not even exactly sure what a confidence region for a subset of parameters means. I want to say something like the following. Let $Q$ be a rank $s$ projection on $\mathbb{R}^r$ so that $QQ=Q$ (I don't know if $Q$ should be an orthogonal projection). Now $C(p, Q)\subset \text{im}(Q)$ is a confidence region for $Q\theta_0$ with confidence level $p$ if
$$
P(Q\theta_0 \in C(p, Q)) = p
$$
but I don't know if I have this right.
But I do definitely know that if $S$ is a rank-$s$ projection (I think orthogonal or oblique is fine) then
$$
Z^TSZ \sim \chi^2_s 
$$
because it is like projecting an $r$-sphere representing the probability distribution for $Z$ onto an $s$-sphere.
So, from that it seems like there should be somewhere I can insert an projection matrix in
$$
\Lambda(\theta) = \Delta\theta^T\mathcal{I}\Delta\theta 
$$
to get the desired answer but I can't figure out exactly how to do it. Is there an intuitive approach, ideally matrix based similar to what I've shown above to show how to define the appropriate $\Lambda_Q(\theta)\sim\chi^2_s$ that can be used to construct lower dimensional confidence intervals?

Two references I'm looking at are

Numerical Recipes in C: The Art of Scientific Computing chapter 15.6
Weighing the Odds: A Course in Probability and Statistics especially 377L, Heuristic explanation of Wilks' Chi-Squared Principle

These very much hint at what I'm talking about, but I'm not able to put all the pieces together.

Note: I think this question is a better thought out version of this one I recently asked.

Do you wish to find the confidence region of $\boldsymbol\theta_1$ in $\boldsymbol\theta:=(\boldsymbol\theta_1, \boldsymbol\theta_2)^\top$?

@User1865345 yes, assuming $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are vectors.

How does this differ from your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/655496?

@whuber like I say in my edit at the end of this question it's very similar. This one just came after I understood some more about my question so I thought I stated it more clearly. If you or other agree this question is better I'm happy to close the other one, or incorporate useful parts of the other one here. Either way, User1865345 hit the nail on the head, I'm trying to find the confidence region for $\theta_1$ in $\theta: (\theta_1, \theta_2)^T$. However, I would intuitively appreciate an approach similar to what I laid out in the question. i.e. using a similar matrix formalism.

The OP is essentially asking for (at least a sketch of) a proof of Wilks' theorem. The projection idea has some of the correct ideas for constructing the confidence regions, but it is not used in the way the OP expected to establish the relationship with likelihood ratios.
Preliminary setup
Suppose we have made an observation $x$ of a random variable $X\sim D(\theta_0)$ where $D(\theta)$ is a generic distribution controlled by parameter $\theta\in \mathbb{R}^r$.  The "true" value of the parameter controlling the distribution of $X$ is given by $\theta_0$. The likelihood function for observing the data $x$ as a function of the parameter $\theta$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta, x).
$$
We will leave off the $x$ dependence since we are primarily concerned with the behavior as a function of $\theta$. The log-likelihood function is defined as
$$
\ell(\theta) = \log(\mathcal{L}(\theta)).
$$
The maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}$ for $\theta_0$ is calculated by maximizing the log-likelihood function:
$$
\hat{\theta} = \text{argmax}_{\theta}(\ell(\theta)).
$$
The (observed) Fisher information is defined by
$$
J_{ij}(\theta) = -\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j}\Bigg\vert_{\theta}.
$$
Furthermore, we define the covariance matrix
$$
C = J^{-1}\left(\hat{\theta}\right) = J^{-1}.
$$
A central fact in likelihood theory is that $\hat{\theta}$ is asymptotically distributed as
$$
\hat{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\theta_0, C\right).
$$
$C$ has been so named because it is the covariance matrix for $\hat{\theta}$.
Multivariate Normal Distributions
We require two facts about multivariate normal distributions.
Fact #1
Suppose $Y$ is an $r$-dimensional multivariate normal distributed random vector:
$$
Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{Y}, C).
$$
Then it can be shown using a Cholesky decomposition that
$$
\left(Y-\bar{Y}\right)^TC^{-1}\left(Y - \bar{Y}\right) \sim \chi^2_r.
$$
Fact #2
Suppose $Y$ is an $r$-dimensional  multivariate normally distributed random vector:
$$
Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{Y}, C).
$$
Now suppose
$$
Y = \begin{pmatrix}Y_1 \\ Y_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $Y_1$ is an $s$ dimensional random vector and $Y_2$ is an $r-s$ dimensional random vector.
We also express
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
C_{11} & C_{12}\\
C_{21} & C_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
broken apart similarly. Then it is the case that $Y_1$ is marginally distributed as
$$
Y_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{Y}_1, C_{11}).
$$
Confidence Regions for the Maximum Likelihood Estimator
From the above discussion and the fact that
$$
\hat{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta_0, C)
$$
it is clear that
$$
\left(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0\right)^T C^{-1}\left(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0\right) \sim \chi^2_r
$$
We can decompose $\hat{\theta}$ and $\theta_0$ as
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{\theta} =& \begin{pmatrix}\hat{\phi}\\\hat{\nu}\end{pmatrix}\\
\hat{\theta}_0 =& \begin{pmatrix}\hat{\phi}_0\\\hat{\nu}_0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
Where $\phi$ is $s$ dimensional and $\nu$ is $r-s$ dimensional.
If we decompose
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}C_{\phi\phi} & C_{\phi\nu}\\C_{\nu\phi} & C_{\nu\nu}\end{pmatrix}
$$
then we know
$$
\left(\hat{\phi} - \phi_0\right)^TC_{\phi\phi}^{-1}\left(\hat{\phi} - \phi_0\right) \sim \chi^2_s.
$$
We define
$$
\Lambda_s(\phi) = \left(\phi - \phi_0\right)^TC_{\phi\phi}^{-1}\left(\phi - \phi_0\right).
$$
We can then define our desired confidence region as
$$
C_s(p) = \left\{\phi: \Lambda_s(\phi) < \text{PPF}_{\chi^2_s}(p)\right\}
$$
so that
$$
P\left(\phi_0\in C_s(p)\right) = P\left(\Lambda_s(\phi)<\text{PPF}_{\chi^2_s}(p)\right) = \text{CDF}_{\chi^2_s}\left(\text{PPF}_{\chi^2_s}(p)\right) = p.
$$
At this point we indeed have already constructed the desired confidence interval $C_s(p)$.
Note that it was not necessary to calculate any likelihood ratio to construct this confidence region. The log-likelihood was only used to find the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}$ and its covariance matrix $C = J^{-1}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)$.
Likelihood Ratios
We now relate the above expressions and intervals to likelihood ratios.
We consider the Taylor expansion of $\ell(\theta)$ about $\hat{\theta}$:
$$
\ell(\theta) \approx \ell\left(\hat{\theta}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\theta - \hat{\theta}\right)^T J\left(\hat{\theta}\right)\left(\theta - \hat{\theta}\right).
$$
We note that $\nabla \ell\left(\hat{\theta}\right)$ was excluded because it zero at $\hat{\theta}$, the maximizer of $\ell$ and we note the minus sign arising because $J$ is the negative Hessian of $\ell$. We can rewrite this as
$$
\Lambda(\theta) = 2\left(\ell\left(\hat{\theta}\right) - \ell(\theta)\right) = \left(\hat{\theta} - \theta\right)^TC^{-1}\left(\hat{\theta} - \theta\right).
$$
So we know immediately that $\Lambda(\theta_0) \sim \chi^2_r$. This means $r$-dimensional confidence regions can be calculated from the likelihood ratio
$$
\Lambda(\theta)= 2\left(\ell\left(\hat{\theta}\right) - \ell(\theta)\right) =2\log\left(\frac{\mathcal{L}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)}{\mathcal{L}(\theta)}\right).
$$
However, I again emphasize that we didn't really need the likelihood ratio and that we could already construct the confidence region once we knew $C$.
We still need to relate the confidence region for an $s<r$ dimensional confidence region for $\phi$ to a likelihood ratio. This requires some slightly more complicated manipulations.
First we define
$$
\tilde{\nu}_{\phi} = \text{argmax}_{\nu}\left(\ell\left(\left(\phi, \nu\right)^T\right)\right)
$$
where
$$
\theta = \begin{pmatrix}\phi \\ \nu\end{pmatrix} = (\phi, \nu)^T.
$$
We then Taylor expand the gradient of the log-likelihood
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_i}\Bigg\vert_{\theta}\approx& \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_i}\Bigg\vert_{\hat{\theta}} + \frac{\partial^2\ell}{\partial \theta_j \theta_i}\Bigg\vert_{\hat{\theta}}\left(\theta_j - \hat{\theta}_j\right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
Noting that the order of differentiation can be reversed and that $\partial \ell/\partial \theta_i\big\vert_{\hat{\theta}} = 0$ because $\hat{\theta}$ is a maximum of $\ell$ we can write this as
$$
\nabla \ell(\theta) \approx -J\left(\theta - \hat{\theta}\right).
$$
Now let us evaluate this at
$$
\tilde{\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}\phi \\ \tilde{\nu}_{\phi}\end{pmatrix},
$$
the projection of $\theta$ onto the values of $\nu$ that maximize $\ell$ for a given $\phi$.
$$
\nabla \ell\left(\tilde{\theta}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}\nabla_{\phi}\ell\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)\\\nabla_{\nu}\ell\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)\end{pmatrix} =
-\begin{pmatrix}
J_{\phi\phi} & J_{\phi\nu}\\J_{\nu\phi} & J_{\nu\nu}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\phi - \hat{\phi}\\\nu - \hat{\nu}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $\nabla_{\phi/\nu}\ell\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)$ represent first $s$ or last $r-s$ components of $\nabla \ell \left(\tilde{\theta}\right)$.
But because $\tilde{\theta}$ is maximized with respect to $\nu$ we have that $\nabla_{\nu}\ell\left(\tilde{\theta}\right) = 0$.
This means we can write
$$
0 = -J_{\nu\phi}\left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)  - J_{\nu\nu}\left(\nu - \hat{\nu}\right)
$$
so that
$$
\nu - \hat{\nu} = -J_{\nu\nu}^{-1}J_{\nu\phi}\left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)
$$
which means we can write $\tilde{\theta} - \hat{\theta}$ as
$$
\tilde{\theta} - \hat{\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}\phi - \hat{\phi}\\\tilde{\nu}_{\phi} - \hat{\nu}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}I_s\\-J_{\nu\nu}^{-1}J_{\nu\phi}\end{pmatrix}\left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right).
$$
That is we can express $\tilde{\theta} - \hat{\theta}$ entirely in terms of $\phi - \hat{\phi}$. The intuition for this is that we have reduced the dimensionality of the problem by projecting on the maximizing values of $\nu$.
Next we define tentatively $\tilde{\Lambda}_s(\phi) = \Lambda\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)$ and calculate
$$
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\Lambda}_s(\phi) = \Lambda\left(\tilde{\theta}\right) =& \left(\tilde{\theta} - \hat{\theta}\right)^TJ\left(\tilde{\theta} - \hat{\theta}\right)\\
=& 
\left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)^T
\begin{pmatrix}I_s\\-J_{\nu\nu}^{-1}J_{\nu\phi}\end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix}J_{\phi\phi} & J_{\phi\nu}\\J_{\nu\phi} & J_{\nu\nu}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}I_s\\-J_{\nu\nu}^{-1}J_{\nu\phi}\end{pmatrix}
\left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)\\
=& \left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)^T\left(J_{\phi\phi} - J_{\phi\nu}J_{\nu\nu}^{-1}J_{\nu\phi}\right)\left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)\\
=& \left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)^T\tilde{J}\left(\phi - \hat{\phi}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Now if we had that $\tilde{J} = C_{\phi\phi}^{-1}$ then we would have $\tilde{\Lambda}_s(\phi)  = \Lambda_s(\phi)$ defined above and we could proceed as we did for the $r$ dimensional case. However, it is indeed the case that $\tilde{J} = C_{\phi\phi}^{-1}$. This follows because $\tilde{J}$ is the Schur complement of $J_{\nu\nu}$ in $J$
$$
J/J_{\nu\nu} = J_{\phi\phi} - J_{\phi\nu}J_{\nu\nu}^{-1}J_{\nu\phi} = \tilde{J}
$$
and it is the case that
$$
C_{\phi\phi} = \left(J^{-1}\right)_{\phi\phi} = \left(J/J_{\nu\nu}\right)^{-1} = \tilde{J}^{-1}
$$
as needed so that $\tilde{\Lambda}_s(\phi) = \Lambda_s(\phi)$ and
$$
\Lambda_s(\phi)=\Lambda\left(\tilde{\theta}\right) = 2\left(\ell\left(\hat{\theta}\right) - \ell\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)\right) = 2\log\left(\frac{\mathcal{L}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)}{\mathcal{L}\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)}\right).
$$
We can then, again, construct the confidence intervals
$$
C_s(p) = \left\{\phi: \Lambda_s(\phi) < \text{PPF}_{\chi^2_s}(p)\right\}.
$$
The One-Dimensional Case
Suppose $\hat{\theta}$ is an $r$ dimensional maximum likelihood estimator but we seek a one-dimensional confidence interval for $\hat{\theta}_1$. We construct
$$
\begin{align*}
\Lambda_1(\phi) =& \left(\hat{\phi} - \phi\right)^TC_{\phi\phi}^{-1}\left(\hat{\phi} - \phi\right)\\
=& \frac{\left(\hat{\theta}_1 - \theta_1\right)^2}{C_{11}}.
\end{align*}
$$
So $\Lambda_1(\phi) < \text{PPF}_{\chi^2}(p)$ corresponds to
$$
\hat{\theta}_1 -\sqrt{\text{PPF}_{\chi^2}(p)}\sqrt{C_{11}} < \theta_1 < \hat{\theta}_1 + \sqrt{\text{PPF}_{\chi^2}(p)}\sqrt{C_{11}}.
$$
If we define $c_p$ = $\sqrt{\text{PPF}_{\chi^2}(p)}$ and $\sigma_1 = \sqrt{C_{11}}$ then we can express the confidence interval as
$$
\theta_1 = \hat{\theta}_1 \pm c_p\sigma_1.
$$
Summary
In summary, we have shown how to calculate confidence intervals for
$$
\hat{\theta} = \text{argmax}_{\theta}\left(\ell(\theta)\right)
$$
using the fact that $\hat{\theta}$ is asymptotically distributed as
$$
\hat{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\theta_0, J^{-1}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)\right)
$$
where $J\left(\hat{\theta}\right)$ is the Hessian of $\ell(\theta)$ at $\hat{\theta}$.
This was done by looking at ellipsoids in parameter space generated by the covariance matrix $C = J^{-1}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)$ and noting that certain related expressions, evaluated at $\theta_0$, are distributed as $\chi^2_r$ or $\chi^2_s$. From these expressions we were able to construct confidence intervals for $\hat{\theta}$.
After having shown how to calculate the confidence intervals, we showed, with some complication, how the expression $\Lambda_s(\phi)$ can be related to the log-likelihood ratio
$$
\Lambda_s(\phi) = \left(\hat{\phi} - \phi\right)^T C_{\phi\phi}\left(\hat{\phi} - \phi\right) =  2\log\left(\frac{\mathcal{L}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)}{\mathcal{L}\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)}\right)
$$
where $\tilde{\theta}$ is the projection of $\theta$ onto the value of $\nu$ that maximizes $\ell(\theta)$ or $\mathcal{L}(\theta)$ for the given value of $\phi$.
A Note about Usage
Above I made heavy use heavy use of the asymptotic normality of $\hat{\theta}$. In the asymptotic limit, we have that the covariance of $\hat{\theta}$ is given by $C=J^{-1}$ and $\ell(\theta)$ is well approximated as an $r$ dimensional paraboloid and the $s$ dimensional  confidence regions are $s$ dimensional ellipsoids.
In these cases it does not matter if we use
$$
\tag{1}
\Lambda_s(\phi) = \left(\hat{\phi} - \phi\right)^T C^{-1} \left(\hat{\phi} - \phi\right)
$$
or
$$
\tag{2}
\Lambda_s(\phi) = 2\log\left(\frac{\mathcal{L}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)}{\mathcal{L}\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)}\right)
$$
to construct the confidence intervals.
However, if we are not well into the asymptotic limit then $\hat{\theta}$ may not be normally distributed and $\ell(\theta)$ may no longer be approximated by a paraboloid. In these cases can still use expressions $(1)$ or $(2)$ to construct confidence regions. If we use $(1)$ then we will still get ellipsoidal confidence regions. If we use $(2)$ we will got non-ellipsoidal confidence regions. In either case the coverage of the confidence regions may be poor because

$\hat{\theta}$ is not normally distributed,
$C=J^{-1}$ may be a poor estimator of the actual covariance of $\hat{\theta}$,
$\left(\hat{\phi} - \phi_0\right)^T C_{\phi\phi} \left(\hat{\phi} - \phi_0\right)$ may not be distributed as $\chi^2_s$,
$\ell(\theta)$ may not be approximated as a paraboloid.

I do not know if these assumptions break down at the same time. If they do, which I suspect, then it seems like regardless of whether you use $(1)$ or $(2)$ to construct the confidence regions you should be suspicious of the coverage of those regions.
References

Weighing the Odds: A Course in Probability and Statistics especially 377L, Heuristic explanation of Wilks' Chi-Squared Principle
Proof of Wilks’ Theorem on LRT
Numerical Recipes in C: The Art of Scientific Computing Section 15.6

